# Magento 2 remove Meta Tag robots From whole Website

Tags: magento2.2.2, seo, meta-tags

Doe anyone know where and how to remove `<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>`  tag for good?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that you want to make `noindex` for google . right?

Comment: Just goto `Login in your Magento admin backend Select Content -> Design  -> Configuration` Select Theme in Website View -> than changes  `Search Engine Robots` = `NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW`

Comment: @Amit Bera No Remove actually remove completely it I've been asked by SEO team said that robot.txt will handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such case, you need to override the `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer`

As this class's the method `renderMetadata` responsible for meta title render.
On the override class's at that method add this condition:

```
        // add this code for stop render of robot
        if ($name = 'robots') {
            continue;
        }
```

**Override function may be look**

```
public function renderMetadata()
    {
        $result = '';
        foreach ($this->pageConfig->getMetadata() as $name => $content) {
            $metadataTemplate = $this->getMetadataTemplate($name);
            if (!$metadataTemplate) {
                continue;
            }
            // add this code for stop render of robot
            if ($name == 'robots') {
                continue;
            }
            $content = $this->processMetadataContent($name, $content);
            if ($content) {
                $result .= str_replace(['%name', '%content'], [$name, $content], $metadataTemplate);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to remove the tag from the code as this is a back-end setting. You can change the setting by logging in to your back-office then go to

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

then click on the correct storeview. Under the tab `Search Engine Robots` you find the option

Comment: I can not able to update, It's disabled.